# Finding the angle formed by the tangents of a triangle inscribed in a square

Tags: proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, angle

> In the following image, $ABCD$ is a square and $AEF$ is an isosceles
> triangle with $|AF|=|AE|$, such that $E$ and $F$ are on segments $BC$ and $DC$, respectively.
> Point $I$ is the barycentre of $AEF$ and circle $c$ has centre $I$ and
> is tangent to $FE$ in $J$. $AK$ and $AL$ are the tangents to circle
> $c$ from point $A$. Find the measure of  $\angle{BAL}$.

[image]

Any ideas to this problem? I did notice that the points of tangency of lines $AK$ and $AL$ to circle $c$ form with point $J$ an equilateral triangle. I feel like that could be the key to the solution but I can't seem to find anything to go further (also it looks like those points form a parallel line to $FE$ but I can't find a succesful proof of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $I$ is the centroid, we have that $AI = 2IJ$. Letting $P$ and $Q$ be the $2$ tangency points, we then have that $\angle IPA = \angle IQA = 90^{\circ}$ and $AI = 2IP = 2IQ$. However, this means that $\triangle IPA$ and $\triangle IPQ$ are *30-60-90 triangles*, so $\angle BAL = 45 - \angle IAP = \boxed{15^{\circ}}$

Comment: Amazing! I was forgetting about the centroid and radius-relation!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $AI=\frac 23AJ$.  There is nothing to locate $J$ in the problem.  If you trust the problem setter to ensure a unique solution, it cannot depend on where $J$ is.  Probably the easiest place is $J=C$.  Now figure out where $I$ is and the radius of the circle.  If you are not willing to trust the problem setter, you need to demonstrate that the positions of $K$ and $L$ do not depend on where $J$ is.